# Add href to class in jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a class :

```
<section class="banner booking-widget-home" data-path="/content/xxx/yyy/en/jcr:content/bookingwidget" data-bgset="/content/dam/xxx/aa-website/banner/2018/pppp/2018/04/abc%def%20Fare_Web%20Banner.png" style="background-image: url(&quot;https://www.abc.in/content/dam/pqr/website/banner/2018/target/2018/04/abc%20Flexi%20Fare_Web%20Banner.png&quot;);">
```

I want to add href on this class so that when I click the background image, the click should take me to the url mentioned in href.
I have tried using :
`$(".banner.booking-widget-home").attr("href","www.landingpae.com");`

but the background image is not clickable.

Comment: This might have added `href` but this is not a `<a>` tag, so it won't work.

Comment: No use of add `href` on this `<section>` tag.

Comment: I tried this also :  jQuery("<a href='www.landingpae.com'</a>").insertAfter(".banner.booking-widget-home");

Comment: You can do something like that, on a click event: `$(document).ready(function(){$('.booking-widget-home').on('click', function(){
    window.location = 'www.landingpae.com';
  });});`

Comment: @AmbikaTewari I have just given an alternate answer. Let me know if that works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it's not an `<a>` tag, the `<section>` will not be clickable. Instead of using `href` use `onclick` and use `location.href`:

```js
$(function () {
  $(".banner.booking-widget-home").click(function () {
    location.href = "https://example.com/";
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section style="background: url('//placehold.it/100?text=Click+Me') center center; width: 100px; height: 100px; cursor: pointer;" class="banner booking-widget-home"></section>
```

Comment: Hi Praveen, Right that works. But I want to open the redirected url in different tab and not in same tab.checking how can I add target="_blank" attribute .

Comment: @AmbikaTewari Just replace `location.href = "https://example.com/";` with `window.open("https://example.com/");` Simple.